# Send notify in another session postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, terminate, postgresql-11

I need to terminate queries by

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid);
```

which work in another session.

How can I send notify or message for that user in another session? So I dont want, that user see an error.
P.s. I know some information about this users, client_addr and user_name and maybe client_hostname.

Comment: If you kill a database session, the client will get an error. That is unavoidable.

Comment: Maybe I can send additional notify?

Comment: If somebody listens, sure.